# Is there a way to remove the Pulse updates section on the LinkedIn homepage?

Tags: linkedin

When I log into LinkedIn, I see [Pulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_%28Application%29) updates at the top of my screen, and I find them often not applicable. Is there a way to stop the Pulse updates on the LinkedIn homepage (that is, to remove it or suppress it or rearrange its location on the page)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I too would like to disable unnecessary updates, but I did not find an option in my settings, so I added `<LI id="today-news-wrapper" class="feed-item today-news-el tod-wrpr">` to the AdBlock browser extension.

In other words:

1. Install the AdBlock extension.
2. Go to AdBlock settings tab #3
3. Edit filters manually—click the **Edit** button.
4. Paste:

   ```
   www.linkedin.com##LI[id="today-news-wrapper"][class="feed-item today-news-el tod-wrpr feed-item-insert"]
   www.linkedin.com##LI[id="today-news-wrapper"][class="feed-item today-news-el tod-wrpr"]
   ```

   in the textarea.
5. Click the **Save** button.

Reload LinkedIn home page.

Comment: that solution rocks!! Admittedly it is a workaround but it delivers the end result.

Comment: @Alex I wouldn't forget that part! It was down voted previously by some ingrate unfortunately, cancelling out my upvote! (user can check their reputation section to see the details)

Comment: @Bartley It was rightfully down-voted, as the very first version of the answer was “+1 to question. Also would like to disable unnecessary updates.”, which was by no means useful.

Comment: I run Adblock Plus 2.4 on Firefox, but don't see a third tab. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I use the following Adblock Plus recipe, under Ad Blocking Rules:

```
linkedin.com###today-news-wrapper
```

Source: https://adblockplus.org/en/filter-cheatsheet#elementselection

To apply this solution:

Press **control-shift-f** or click on the AdBlock icon in your browser > Select **Filter Preferences**, then click on the tab called **Custom filters**.  You should see an item called **Ad Blocking Rules**. Click on that and on the "actions" button, click **Show Rules**. You'll then see a pane appear in the right hand side. There you can **Add Filter**. Click that button and copy and paste the above text there. Close the Adblock Plus pop up box and you're set.

When you now go to the LinkedIn homepage, you'll see the LinkedIn Pulse News section is no longer visible.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down voted.  It works for me.  @Benjamin wanted this information and I couldn't comment in the other answer because I am a new user.  I'm fine with someone editing the other answer and adding this to it.